# Javascript Library to Test API Endpoints

Tags: javascript, api, rest, jasmine, mocha.js

I am looking for a simple API for testing rest API. I would like to be able to keep the mocha and/or jasmine asserts structure, while chaining the API data, verb etc.

```
api( '/maker' )
   .put(
     return {
       name: 'Sample 1',
       type: 'cheese',
       country: 'United States'
     }
   )
   .failed()
   .succussed().
   .has(
     return {
       assert(1, 1)
     }
   );
```

Answer (score 6):

supertest https://github.com/visionmedia/supertest does exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: My notes after trying frisby and supertest: It is much easier to 'chain' asynchronous requests in supertest, compared to frisby. Also, I like supertest's default of json-encoded request body versus frisby's url-form-encoded default.

Comment: Supertest also seems to let you make use of jasmine's `done` callback, which facilitates running asynchronous tests serially.

Answer (score 6):

Frisby.js https://github.com/vlucas/frisby is another one. It's jasmine based.